# Styles in css file not showing on html template

Tags: python, css, django

**css not linking in django**

iam trying to create an ecommerce website for my project and made a css file and linked it to the base template. But those results are not to be seen.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),]
```

**Base template css linking**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/csss" href="{% static '/css/custom.css' %}">
```

**CSS**

```
body{font-family: 'Roboto',
sans-serif;
background-color:#D3D3D3;
}
.text-center{
font-family:roboto;
}
.card-title{
font-weight:bold;
font-family:'Roboto',
sans-serif;
}
/*footer*/
.foot{
background-color:blue;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0; left:0;
 height:10px; width:100%;
}

h2{
font-family:'roboto',sans-serif;
}
/*cart-icons*/
.custom_icon{
margin:7px;
font-size:20px;
color:blue;
}
/*invoice*/
.inv{
display:block;
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from cart import views

app_name='cart'

urlpatterns=[
    path('cart_view',views.cart_view,name='cart_view'),
    path('add_cart/<int:p>',views.add_cart,name='add_cart'),
    path('add_cart/<int:p>',views.add_cart,name='add_cart'),
    path('minus/<int:p>',views.minus,name='minus'),
    path('delete/<int:p>',views.delete,name='delete'),
    path('order',views.order,name='order'),
    path('invoice',views.invoice,name='invoice'),
]
```

I linked the css to base template, but not seeing any results, inline styling is working though.
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUz55.png)

Comment: share your `urls.py` and you project structure

Comment: This problem can also be replicated using plain html/css. Assuming that isn't a copy/paste mistake, `type="text/csss"` should be `type="text/css"` (Worked in the simple reproduction using html/css and also using a simple django-setup).

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}">
```

Comment: Hi, while your answer may address the question, it would be better to include some [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)